# Find start and end of abrupt changes in an arrary in Python

Tags: python, arrays

Very new to Python and seems to me this task is not solvable based on my learning.

Please help:

1. I have an array created by the Python program, which provides a 1d array like this:

   `[0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,0.01,.1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1]`
2. You can see the array number go from zero to max and then again to zero many times.
3. I need to find index where it starts to go up and down every time. So here it would be `[3,9,12,17,20,26,29]`

This is what I tried so far, but in vain

```
My_array==[0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,0.01,.1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1]

def _edge(ii):
    for i in range (ii, len(My_array)):
        if np.abs(My_array[i]-My_array[i-1])>.01;
        index=i # save the index where the condition met
        break

    for ii in range (1, len(My_array))

    if ii <len(My_array): # make sure the loop continues till the end
        F1_Index=_edge(ii)
        F1_Index1.append(F1_Index)
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the "return index" in "def".

Comment: What sort of output do you get when you run this code?

Comment: its getting hanged in F1_Index=_edge(ii) and if I click next (in debug mode) it takes me to sitecustomize.py. Thanks Sam for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use numpy you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,0.01,.1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1])
b = a[1:] - a[:-1]  # find differences between sequential elements
v = abs(b) == 0.01  # find differences whose magnitude are 0.01
                    # This returns an array of True/False values
edges = v.nonzero()[0] # find indexes of True values
edges += 2  # add 1 because of the differencing scheme, 
            # add 1 because the results you give in the question 
            # are 1 based arrays and python uses zero based arrays
edges
>  array([ 3,  9, 12, 17, 20, 26, 29], dtype=int64)
```

This is the fastest way I've found to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Brad, Thanks for the answer, I think you this was very simple to understand. I modified your code to get what I want and is now working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following I think does what you need. It first builds a list holding `-1`, `0` or `1` giving the difference between adjacent values (unfortunately `cmp` has been removed from Python 3 as this was the perfect function for doing this). It then uses the `groupby` function and a non-zero filter to generate a list of indexes for when the direction changes:

```
import itertools

My_array = [0, 0, .01, .1, 1, 1, .1, .01, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, .1, 1, .1, .01, 0, 0, 0, .01, .1, 1, 1, .1, .01, 0, 0, 0, .01, .1, 1, 1]

def my_cmp(x,y):
    if x == y:      # Or for non-exact changes use:  if abs(x-y) <= 0.01:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 if y > x else -1

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

slope = [(my_cmp(pair[1], pair[0]), index) for index, pair in enumerate(pairwise(My_array))]
indexes_of_changes = [next(g)[1]+1 for k,g in itertools.groupby(slope, lambda x: x[0]) if k != 0]

print(indexes_of_changes)
```

Giving you the following result for your data:

```
[2, 6, 11, 14, 19, 23, 28]
```

Note, this gives you ANY change in direction, not just `> 0.01`.

Tested using Python 3.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the answer. Not able to test as I am using Python3 and cmp is not recognize. Was reading some post that "key" should be used instead of "cmp".

Comment: I was using `cmp` as a function to give `-1` `0` or `1`, not for sorting, so it is needed as is. I have reimplemented a version for Python 3 which could be modified to give non-exact changes also.

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks for the corrections. I find the code by Brad much easier for me to understand so I am working around it to get what I need. Thanks indeed.

Comment: Indeed, numpy is very powerful for doing this. Not all installations have access to it so it always useful to have an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I did it which is working for me (mostly learned from Brad's code). Still quite do not understand how b.nonzero()[0] is working,. Brad please explain, if possible.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,0.01,.1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1,.1,.01,0,0,0,.01,.1,1,1])
b0=[x>.1 for x in a] # making array of true and false
b0=np.array(b0) 
b0=b0*1# converting true false to 1 and 0
b=abs(b0[1:]-b0[:-1])# now I only have 1 where there is a change
edges = b.nonzero()[0] # find indexes of 1 values
edges
```

> array([ 3,  5, 12, 13, 20, 22, 29], dtype=int64)